# Change property name of stdClass Object

Tags: php, json, woocommerce

I am writing json response for woocommerce website for new mobile app. I am totally new to json,php,woocommerce.

From lot of searching I got this API working.[this](https://github.com/helpforfitness/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library-v2)

I am getting response like this when I use this line

`$data = $client->products->get('', array('filter[limit]' => '500'));`

```
stdClass Object
(
    [products] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [title] => Malai tikka roll
                    [id] => 2580
                    [created_at] => 2017-05-22T08:13:56Z
                    [updated_at] => 2017-05-22T08:14:38Z
                    [type] => simple
                    [status] => publish
                    [downloadable] => 
                    [virtual] => 
                    [permalink] => http://localhost/fooddemo/product/malai-tikka-roll/
                    [sku] => 
                    [price] => 75.00
                    [regular_price] => 75.00
                    [sale_price] =>
```

Now I want to do is change some fields and send json response through `$response` object to my android app.

I tried doing this but it gives me error
`$response["Title"] = $data["title"];`

> Undefined index: title in C:\xampp\htdocs\demoservice\productlist.php
>   on line 15

Sample code

```
<?php 
require_once( 'lib/woocommerce-api.php' );
$options = array(
    'debug'           => true,
    'return_as_array' => false,
    'validate_url'    => false,
    'timeout'         => 30,
    'ssl_verify'      => false,
);
$response = array("error" => FALSE);
try{
    require_once( 'key.php' );
    $data = $client->products->get('', array('filter[limit]' => '500'));
    //echo json_encode($response);
    $response["Title"] = $data["title"];
}catch ( WC_API_Client_Exception $e ) {

    require_once( 'catch.php' );
}
```

Comment: foreach($data as $value){$response["Title"][]=$value->title;}.. try this

Comment: It gives Notice  Trying to get property of non-object in

Comment: Notice  Undefined index: title and prints this Array
(
    [error] => 
    [Title] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
        )

)

Comment: i solve your issue and i have upload the answer and you can get n numbers of array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

products is a property of the main object, and in itself is an array. This is what you're after:

```
foreach($data->products as $d) {
   echo $d->title, '<br />', $d->id, '<br />', $d->status;
}
```

If you want to access one of those element without a loop, you need to provide the array index, for example:

```
echo $data->products [0]->title
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you replace

```
$response["Title"] = $data["title"];
```

with:

```
$response["Title"] = $data->products[0]->title;
```

Comment: It gives Notice Trying to get property of non-object in and print this Array
(
    [error] => 
    [Title] => 
)

Comment: I've modified my answer a bit.

Comment: Ok! it works, Now there are n number of products 0,1,2,....n How can i have response of all in one veriable